# How to implement a click event in CustomLabel control?

Tags: winforms

I need to detect when a System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomLabel is clicked, I can´t find an implementation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Chart.HitTest() method in an event handler for its MouseDown event.  It tells you what got clicked.